# Sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT 'Values ("'+ S.enroll_no +'",'+ Pm.periodname COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT +'),'
FROM   studentattendencedetails AS SA 
      LEFT JOIN studentattendencemaster AS SM 
         ON SA.attendencemasterid = SM.id 
      LEFT JOIN tbl_periodmaster AS Pm 
         ON SA.periodid = Pm.id 
      LEFT JOIN students AS S 
         ON SA.studentid = S.id 
WHERE  SA.isabsent = 2 
ORDER  BY S.enroll_no
```

OutPut:

```
ColumnName
Values ("XXXXXX",2),
Values ("XXXXXX",1),
Values ("YYYYYYY",2),
Values ("YYYYYYY",1),
```

But I would like to add "Values" only for the first row in the list as follows and need to remove "," from last row.

Required Output:

```
ColumnName
Values ("XXXXXX",2),
("XXXXXX",1),
("YYYYYYY",2),
("YYYYYYY",1)
```

Comment: I Guess this question is related to this question you asked hours ago. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51184828/stuff-query-with-multiple-joins/51186039#51186039 - Why do you wanna make these values dynamic when you already have them? Cant you just use INSERT INTO dbo.XXXX Select Yourcolumns from XXXX

Comment: You are preparing columns for concatenation, this is needless. When the time comes to concatenate, just use 'Values' + stuff(.....) per Gordon Linoff's answer on your other post that Thomas mentioned. This will have values in the beginning, and no comma in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this one.

`with cte as 
(SELECT row_number() over(partition by enroll_no ORDER BY S.enroll_no) rn, S.enroll_no +'",'+ Pm.periodname COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT +'),' long_string
FROM   studentattendencedetails AS SA 
      LEFT JOIN studentattendencemaster AS SM 
         ON SA.attendencemasterid = SM.id 
      LEFT JOIN tbl_periodmaster AS Pm 
         ON SA.periodid = Pm.id 
      LEFT JOIN students AS S 
         ON SA.studentid = S.id 
WHERE  SA.isabsent = 2)
select case 
            when rn = 1 then 'Values ("'+ cte.long_string
            else cte.long_string
        end
from cte`